# How to get token in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, api

I make request with my data. I want to get token from Instagram API. When I paste my url in browser, I see token. But I need to get it programmatically. How can I do it?

```
 webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
```

Answer (score -1):

You just want to read the token from the header? You could try this. Set:

```
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

And then in the `WKNavigationDelegate` method:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    print(navigationAction.request.allHTTPHeaderFields)
}
```